# Matlab maxima function

Tags: matlab, function

I've got a problem with my function. It's supposed to take the signal and time data and output two vectors of the times of the maximums and the maxima signals. What I've done is try to use the findpeaks function to create a pks and locs array, then initialise a blank array the same size as the locs array and then use a for statement to go through and reassign the zeros with the time data of the maximas.

```
function [ max_times, max_signal ] = local_max(time_data, signal_data)
%Finds the local maximum of data

[pks, locs] = findpeaks(signal_data);
max_times = zeros(size(locs));

for n = 1:size(locs);
    max_times(n) = max_signal(locs(n));
end

clear 'locs' 

end
```

This is the error I get:

**Error: File: local_max.m Line: 7 Column: 10
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.**

I don't quite understand what it means/ how I can solve it. Anyone able to help?

Comment: What is `max_signal()` and format of `locs`?

Comment: `max_signal()` and `locs` are 1D double matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get an error is because `max_signal` is not defined when you use it. You probably want:

```
max_times(n) = time_data(locs(n));
```

Also, looping is unnecessary. You can simply do:

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(signal_data);
max_times = time_data(locs);
```

Comment: This should not be the problem. Error happens in `for n = 1:size(locs);`.

Comment: Ahh thanks, didn't realise it would be as simple. However, I've tried this but now I only get a output called "ans", instead of max_times and max_signal like a wanted so I can plot them, also the locs array has disappeared?.

Comment: 1. "The `locs` array has disappeared": Is it because you clear it maybe? And it won't be in the workspace after the function anyway, since it's not one of the output variables.
2. I think there should be a vector called `max_times`.
3. `max_signal` is not there anymore, that's correct. But it never was either. What do you want `max_signal` to be? The same as `pks` maybe?
4. When you call the function, call it this way: `[max_times, max_signal] = local_max(time_data, signal_data)` (that is, you need the arguments on the LHS, or else it will only be saved as `ans`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: I don't think that is correct. Try for n = 1:size(1:4). You don't get any errors. If the input is a row vector it actually works fine. If it is a column vector it will only go through the loop once (not what you want to happen, but still no error).

Comment: I've managed to get it working now, thanks for your (and everyones help)!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `size(locs)` will return `[1, n]`, not a number. So you need to change

```
for n = 1:size(locs);
```

to

```
for n = 1:numel(locs);
```

Comment: I think a better approach would be `size(locs,1)` (or `size(locs,2)` if it's a column vector) or `numel(locs)`.

Comment: I don't think that is why the error message appears. Try for n = 1:size(1:4). You don't get any errors. If the input is a row vector it actually works fine. If it is a column vector it will only go through the loop once (not what you want to happen, but still no errors). I agree that `1:size(locs)` is not a good approach, but it's not causing the error message in this case.

Comment: @RobertP. Not right. I just tested it. I passed a row vector e.g. `locs=[1 2 3 4]`, it will only run once, not 4 times. On the contrary, it will work work for col vector.

Comment: Maybe I phrased it wrong. It works on a vertical vector, not a horizontal one. Anyway, the point being: The error message was not caused by `for i = 1:size(locs)`. =)